# Issue with Circular Depdencies and Factory method

Tags: c#, dependencies

I have a Factory library (project) for creating concrete objects and I have multiple libraries for concrete objects.

Now I want a concrete object library to call Factory Library to get another concrete object. But I cannot do so because of Circular Dependencies. I am using C#.

Is there any solution for this? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Put the code you use in Factory library that need to be used from other libraries inside another library and reference this both in Factory library and in concrete objects libraries...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you post some more information, particularly some code showing what you have tried? It is not easy to answer your question as it stands because it doesn't contain enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try interface design. To do that, use interface for both concrete and factory. Then do constructor injection. You also can do property injection, it's up to you, but constructor injection is better IMHO.

**Project A : Interface for Concrete objects and Factory**

**Then your concrete objects, project B, is references project A.** All Objects are implemented interfaces from A, and take parameters only in interface. Inject the factory instead of creating it inside concrete object. Ex:

```
public class ConcreteObjectA : IConcreteObjectA{
  public ConcreteObjectA(IFactoryObjectB factoryB){
    factoryB.Create();
  }
}
```

**Then your factory objects, project C, is references project B.** All Factory are implemented in interface, and return only interface. Ex:

```
public class FactoryObjectB : IFactoryObjectB {
  public IConcreteObjectB Create(){
    return new ConcreteObjectB();
  }
}
```

The usage from client will be something like this:

```
public void CreateObjectA(){
  FactoryObjectB factory = new FactoryObjectB();
  ConcreteObjectA objectA = new ConcreteObjectA(factory);
}
```

Comment: That works for me. Fendy, you really save my time. Thank you very much. Good day!

Comment: @user2310061 you're welcome. FYI, this design is called Dependency (constructor) Injection, with or without abstract factory pattern.

Answer (score 2):

An useful solution to this is to create a third project where you put methods that point to the other two.

For example:

Project A: Factory Library

Project B: Concrete Objects

Project C (the new one): Method which will use the project B Classes and Project A library.

General: Creating specific projects to split the classes with circular dependencies.

Hope it helps.

Update:

X --> A --> B (Actual)

**Problem:**

B --> A (circular dependencies)

**Solution:**

Split parts of A which are being called from B to a new Project, C (who has to be also pointed from X)

X --> A --> B

X --> C

Problem solved: B --> C (no circular dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But sorry, I m not clear, who will create project C. The existing flow is project X: facade library calls project A:Factory Library to get Project B:Concrete object. now Project B needs to call Project A back to get another Project D:another concrete object.